# Yam file error e error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 8: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, minio

This is my first try in kubernetes. Trying to install minios storage i am finding error in yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
   name: pv-name-1
spec:
   capacity:
      storage: 1Ti
   volumeMode: Filesystem
   accessModes:
   - ReadWriteOnce
   persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
   storage-class: local-storage
   local:
      path: /mnt/d/minio
   nodeAffinity:
      required:
         nodeSelectorTerms:
         - matchExpressions:
            - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
               operator: In
               values:
               - docker-desktop
```

error: error parsing pvc-1.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 8: mapping values are not allowed in this context

I

Answer (score 0):

You had incorrect indentation under affinity. Some 3rd party linter of yaml files specially for kubernetes are hyperlinked [here](https://learnk8s.io/validating-kubernetes-yaml).

Also, `storage-class` should be `storageCalssName`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
   name: pv-name-1
spec:
   capacity:
      storage: 1Ti
   volumeMode: Filesystem
   accessModes:
   - ReadWriteOnce
   persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
   #storage-class: local-storage <--this should be StorageClassName
   local:
      path: /mnt/d/minio
   nodeAffinity:
      required:
         nodeSelectorTerms:
         - matchExpressions:
           - key: kubernetes.io/hostname In #<-----------this and below  lines are moved one place left
             operator: 
             values:
             - docker-desktop
```

Comment: I used this one as well it shows the same error. Error is at line 8 is what it throws. I have used couple of yaml online validator and and syntax looks fine

Comment: when you copy the text from here to your terminal(*assuming* `vim`), use `:set paste` inside vim.

Comment: Also, when you use `storage-class` ,what does you try to set ? dd you meant `storageClassName` ?

Comment: cat pv.yaml
    apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
    kind: StorageClass
    metadata:
        name: local-storage
    provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
    volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
kubectl create -f pv.yaml
kubectl get sc

  kubectl get sc
NAME                 PROVISIONER                    RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE      ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
hostpath (default)   docker.io/hostpath             Delete          Immediate              false                  131m
local-storage        kubernetes.io/no-provisioner   Delete          WaitForFirstConsumer

Comment: I have created another storage class and use that name local-storage for that